# Converting ros::time to double value without uint_t

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a look at the ros::[durationBase](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1DurationBase.html#ad1705cb3762b907aaea61b47217c38b6) and it has functions toSec toNsec to convert the following into one int64_t which would exceed a double in c++;

```
int32_t     nsec
int32_t     sec
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227020/converting-ros::time-to-double-value-without-uint_t/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both, `ros::durationBase` ([API Doc](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1DurationBase.html)) as well as `ros::timeBase` ([API Doc](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1TimeBase.html)) contain the respective `toSec()` functions which return a `double`.  What you did is not required!

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-18**:
So this is also ok? ( I could not get it to run with the function first)

```
double h_time = h.stamp.toSec();
```